# React - Controlled input props are outdated in useCallback

Tags: react-hooks, controlled-component

I have a controlled input where its value and onChange event are set via props. When the `selectedValue` prop changes, `onInputChanged` callback gets triggered, but if I try accessing `selectedValue` in this callback it's out of date.

Seems like when `selectedValue` changes, `onInputChanged` gets called before it has been updated with the new dependencies

I'm probably just not understanding the lifecycle of the component correctly, but is there a way to ensure that I can access the latest `selectedValue` from inside the onChange event? Here's my code:

```
const TestInput = ({ onChange, selectedValue }) => {
  const onInputChanged = React.useCallback(content => {

    // Will not log the latest selectedValue
    console.log(selectedValue);

    onChange(content.target.value);
  }, [selectedValue]);

  return (
    <input value={selectedValue} onChange={onInputChanged} placeholder="Test...." />
  );
};

const TestContainer = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  return <TestInput selectedValue={value} onChange={setValue} />;
};
```

Heres a sandbox link to play around with - https://playcode.io/1042642

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access it from the onChange function, since the function will not be rendered twice to show the new value, you could check it in a useEffect here documentation [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

You could try something like this:

```js
const TestInput = ({ onChange, selectedValue }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
   console.log('selected value', selectedValue);
  }, [selectedValue]);

  const onInputChanged = React.useCallback(content => {
    onChange(content.target.value);
  }, [selectedValue]);

  return (
    <input value={selectedValue} onChange={onInputChanged} placeholder="Test...." />
  );
};

const TestContainer = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  return <TestInput selectedValue={value} onChange={setValue} />;
};
```